# Print task name whenever System.out.println is called

Tags: java, multithreading, multitasking

I wrote a program the runs some threads that calls a method that produces some output. Each threads make some output, like this:

```
a //output made by the thread 1
b //output made by the thread 2
c //output made by the thread 3
d //output made by the thread 2
e //output made by the thread 1
f //output made by the thread 3
```

I would like to print this output in this way:

```
task1:  a //output made by the thread 1
task2:  b //output made by the thread 2
task3:  c //output made by the thread 3
task2:  d //output made by the thread 2
task1:  e //output made by the thread 1
task3:  f //output made by the thread 3
```

I need something that append `task#:` whenever is called a `System.out.println`.

The `run()` mehtod is something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    long start = 0, end = 0;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        myClass.do(param1, param2); //this is the method that produce the output
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Thread time: "+ (end - start));
}
```

This is the method called in `run()`:

```
@Override
public void do(String u, String p) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("output1: "+ u);
    System.out.println("output2: "+ p);
    System.out.println("output3");
}
```

I want that before all `ouput1`, `ouput2`, `ouput3` is shown `task#:`; have you any ideas?

I hope that my explanation is clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some code? It's pretty hard to help you without some context.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the comment, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper way to go about this would be to use a logging API like `java.util.logging` instead of `System.out`. Example:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyTestClass.class.getName());

@Override
public void do(String u, String p) throws IOException {
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "output1: "+ u);
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "output2: "+ p);
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "output3");
}
```

Then you could probably register a custom subclass of [`ConsoleHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) that includes the thread-specific information that is acquired via `Thread.currentThread.getId()` (or a `ThreadLocal` variable, if you need to associate more data with the thread) on its own before printing the actual logging message.

Comment: Thanks, please vote my question if you think that is useful

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display current thread ID which is executing the code, than you can use:

```
System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getId());
```

I am not sure whether you want to display thread ID or not.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can save value to thread locals:

```
ThreadLocal threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();
threadLocal.set("task#1");
String threadLocalValue = (String) threadLocal.get();
```